# Quitting Tkinter application running on infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My application is not quitting cleanly. The error message is:
tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".47654392"

My code is:

```
import math
from tkinter import *
import time
tk=Tk()
c=Canvas(tk,width=800,height=600)
c.pack()
c.create_arc(200,200,250,250,extent=359,style=ARC)
def out():
    tk.after(5,lambda:tk.destroy())
b=Button(tk,text='Quit',command=out)
b.pack(side=BOTTOM)
a=2
theta=math.radians(0)
while a==2:
    for i in range(360):
        siny=math.sin(theta)*1
        cosx=math.cos(theta)*1
        c.move(1,cosx,siny)
        theta=theta+math.radians(1)
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using endless loop `while` you didn't run `tk.mainloop`. So `tkinter` can executes some functions.

And don't use `time.sleep()` because you stop all functions in `tkinter` - use `after()`.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

master = Tk()

c = Canvas(master, width=800, height=600)
c.pack()

c.create_arc(200, 200, 250, 250, extent=359, style=ARC)

b = Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.destroy)
b.pack(side=BOTTOM)

theta = math.radians(0)
rad = math.radians(1)

def move():
    global theta
    siny = math.sin(theta)
    cosx = math.cos(theta)
    c.move(1, cosx, siny)
    theta += rad
    master.update()
    master.after(1, move)

master.after(1, move)

master.mainloop()
```